# Possible ways of distribution of projects among students.

Tags: combinatorics

$18$ student pairs must choose one project from $4$. It is hoped that each project will be chosen at least once but not more than $6$ times.

It is asked to find the number of distinct distributions
of projects, I know how to find it as the solution to the problem $p_1+p_2+p_3+p_4=18$ with $1\le p_i\le 6$ and I denote $n$ this number.

Now it is asked to express the number of possible choices as a sum (this time taking into account the distinction between pairs).
My idea is that for each choice of the previous $n$ choices, we can choose ${18 \choose p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4}=\dfrac{18!}{p_1!p_2!p_3!p_4!}$ but I can't see how to write this as a sum.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of generating functions. The generating function for one project is $$\frac{x^1}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}+\frac{x^6}{6!}$$

Now , find the coefficient of $\frac{x^{18}}{18!}$ in the expansion of $$\bigg(\frac{x^1}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}+\frac{x^6}{6!}\bigg)^4$$

or find the coefficient of $x^{18}$ and multiply it by $18!$.

**[Here is the expansion](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=expanded+form+of+%28x+%2B+x%5E2+%2F2+%2Bx%5E3+%2F6+%2Bx%5E4+%2F24+%2Bx%5E5+%2F120+%2Bx%5E6+%2F720%29%5E4)**

So , $$18! \times \frac{13}{2592000}=32,110,670,592$$

Comment: how to express the number of possible choices as a sum (this time taking into account the distinction between pairs) ?

Comment: @palio if you meant selecting one individual from each pair , you can just add $2^r$ as coefficent such that $$\bigg(\frac{2^1x^1}{1!}+\frac{2^2x^2}{2!}+\frac{2^3x^3}{3!}+\frac{2^4x^4}{4!}+\frac{2^5x^5}{5!}+\frac{2^6x^6}{6!}\bigg)^4$$. The rest is the same , find the coefficient of $x^{18}$ and multiply by $18!$

Comment: I think it is meant to specify which pair took which project.